# How to reference the repository in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I am working on an open source library, and I use [JSDoc](https://github.com/shri/JSDoc-Style-Guide) for documentation. I would like to reference the repository at the top of each file.

I am able to put my name in the comment block using `@author`, but I don't know how should I reference the repository as well. My guess is this:

```
/** 
 *  @author John Doe<john@example.com>
 *  @link https://github.com/john-example/my-repo
 */
```

Is it the right way to do it? Or should I combine `@link` with `@see`?

Many of the classes in my project can be used independently from the library, so it is possible that some users will just copy the files they need. That is the reason, why creating a LICENSE file in the root folder is not enough, and I would like to put the link of the repository at the top of each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `@see` with `@link`, one of the examples is even a link to Github. Put it at the top of your file:

[image: JSDoc documentation for @see - from https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/tags-see]

Read more [here](https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/tags-see). I've gone through all of the docs, but not found anything better.

While not answering your question per se, I'd probably use `@version` with an `@link` to the URL of the release.